# SQL Statement to find only courses on which the current user is not enrolled on

Tags: mysql, select

I am developing a web app which keeps track of an employees training records as part of my uni course.

I am using phpMyadmin and MySQLi.

I have 3 database tables tblUser, tblCourse and tblBookings.

tblUser has UserID, First_Name, Last_Name, Email, Access_Level columns

tblCourse has CourseID, Course_Title, Course_Start_Time, Course_Duration, Course_Description, Max_Attendees columns

tblBookings contains only BookingID, CourseID and UserID which links to the relevant user/course in the other two tables.

```
tblBookings looks something like this
+-----------+----------+--------+
| BookingID | CourseID | UserID |
+-----------+----------+--------+
|         1 |        1 |      1 |
|         2 |        1 |      2 |
|         3 |        1 |      3 |
|         4 |        2 |      2 |
|         5 |        2 |      3 |
|         6 |        3 |      1 |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I am trying to write an SQL statement to populate a table which only displays courses onto which the current user is not enrolled. So in the above scenario for UserID 1 I would want to populate a table with only the course details of the Course with CourseID of 2 as this is the only course which he is not enrolled on.

The closest I have got is with this statement:

```
SELECT `tblCourseAdmin`.`CourseID`, `Course_Title`, `Course_Date`, `Course_Start_Time`, `Course_Duration`, `Course_Description`, `Max_Attendees`
FROM `tblCourseAdmin`
INNER JOIN `tblBookings`
ON `tblCourseAdmin`.`CourseID` = `tblBookings`.`CourseID`
WHERE`tblBookings`.`UserID` != 1
```

But this still pulls up courses in which the user is enrolled if there are other users enrolled on that course.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the table contents and the desired result. It isn't entirely clear exactly what your question is.

Comment: thanks Dave hope that makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join and filter out the matched rows:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM `tblCourseAdmin` c LEFT JOIN `tblBookings` b
ON c.`CourseID` = b.`CourseID` AND b.`UserID` = 1
WHERE b.`UserID` IS NULL
```

The condition `b.UserID = 1` will join the tables only to the courses where that user has enrolled and the condition `WHERE b.UserID IS NULL` will keep only the unmatched rows which are the the courses where that user has **not** enrolled.
See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vj8kv5anQvKHxTXP46PJY5/0).

Comment: This worked perfectly and was exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT `tblCourseAdmin`.`CourseID`, `Course_Title`, `Course_Date`, `Course_Start_Time`, `Course_Duration`, `Course_Description`, `Max_Attendees`
FROM `tblCourseAdmin`
WHERE CourseID NOT IN (
    SELECT CourseID FROM tblBookings WHERE UserID = 1
)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and was really useful to see a second way of achieving the same result. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @wp78de thanks for the previous help. I have since discovered that I also need to filter the courses so that courses which have already taken place are not included in the list and that only courses with spaces left should only display.

Comment: I have therefore added this to your statement

Comment: SELECT `tblCourseAdmin`.`CourseID`, `Course_Title`, `Course_Date`, `Course_Start_Time`, `Course_Duration`, `Course_Description`, `Max_Attendees` FROM `tblCourseAdmin` WHERE `CourseID` NOT IN ( SELECT `CourseID` FROM `tblBookings` WHERE `UserID` = 13) AND `tblCourseAdmin`.`Course_Date` > CURRENT_DATE AND `tblCourseAdmin`.`Max_Attendees` > (SELECT COUNT(ALL `BookingID`) FROM `tblBookings`)

Comment: the date clause works but trying to get the list to only populate with courses where the number of bookings for a course is less than the number of spaces (Max_Attendees) is proving somewhat of a challenge. Any advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @AlanBurnell pardon, I was traveling and could not follow-up.

Comment: Not a problem, I have since added a column to my table which counts the enrolments into the course which I can then use to compare against. This was the only way I could see of doing this. Thank you again though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `LEFT JOIN` (or a right join). The `LEFT JOIN` gets one table and matches it to another table *no matter what*. When there is no match, the columns of the second table get NULLs.

So if you do,

```
SELECT * 
   FROM tblUser
   JOIN tblCourse
```

with no `JOIN` condition, it would pull all the users and all the courses.

Now add

```
   LEFT JOIN tblBookings ON (tblUser.UserID = tblBookings.UserID AND tblBookings.CourseID = tblCourse.CourseID)
```

and this would pull in all users and all courses, and where there is no booking for that user and that course, the tblBookings columns would be `NULL`.

So you now just add a `WHERE` condition

```
   WHERE (tblBookings.UserID IS NULL OR tblBookings.CourseID IS NULL)
```

and get the rows where there is a user, there is a course, but that user is not enrolled in that course. Which seems to be what you were after?

## UPDATE

Sorry, it was *not* what you were after, but close. You want the above, *for the current user*. So you don't need to join with the users table after all:

```
SELECT * 
   FROM tblCourse
   LEFT JOIN tblBookings ON (tblUser.UserID = CURRENT_USER_ID AND tblBookings.CourseID = tblCourse.CourseID)
   WHERE (tblBookings.CourseID IS NULL)
```